# Write power off and power on button press to file

Tags: java, android

I have been poking around to figure out how to do this with `Service` or `Activity`, or Broadcast Receiver and I can't seem to get a definitive answer.

I want to be able to write the following data event(s) with timestamp to a file with an application that is running in the background.

- Power button pressed on
- Call being sent outgoing
- SMS message being sent outgoing

It is an application that I am attempting to build for logging phone usage with the timestamp written to a file.

Went through many explanations and this is the only one that seemed to make sense: 
https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Any information or tutorials on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Create a broadcast receiver that based on the intent received determines the type of event. Have a look to the `Command` design pattern.
2. The command launches a new intent using the Broadcast receiver as a `Context`.
3. Create a service that is able to handle this intent, so it starts, sends some data or stores it wherever, and shutsdown. Have a look to the `IntentService` class.
4. Create an activity to show the content you have stored or to explain the user what your app does.

Comment: Do you know any where that has tutorials on something like this?

Comment: Found this, but it only describes handling phone calls. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: It is pretty similar. I mean change the phone call handling by the screen handling and you get it. I don't think it would be easy to find something like that. Read how to implement a broadcast receiver, how to send an intent, how to listen this intent and finally how to implement an intent service. If you have particular doubts on it I can help you a bit

Comment: Could really use a tutorial. I have a lot of doubts. Been reading android references for days on this. I just need to handle power press on, power press off, call outbound, and sms outbound. Cannot seem to find a good example on this anywhere I have looked. Any information would be very appreciated.